# FreeRtos osDelay is exactly three times too long

Tags: c

Using Nucleo STM32H723 board making an alive LED toggle in the StartDefaultTask.

`osDelay(10000)` gives exactly30 seconds of delay. I'm using timer7 as systick timer.

Bonus info:
FreeRTOSConfig.h
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ                       ( SystemCoreClock )
"SystemCoreClock" is initially set to 64MHz (HSI) but during start-up initialized to 216MHz (SYSClk). If I edit "FreeRTOSConfig.h" and set "configCPU_CLOCK_HZ" to 64000000 osDelay is now correct, but I would like to be able to generate the clock and rtos config with CubeIDE.

Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I am not familiar with that board, but I think the OS thinks SysTick ticks @ 1/3 speed of its actual (hardware) speed. You have to sync that value to the OS. Check your FreeRTOSConfig.h file for configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ value...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that board, but I think the OS thinks SysTick ticks @ 1/3 speed of its actual (hardware) speed. You have to sync that value to the OS. Check your FreeRTOSConfig.h file for configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ and related parameters. As for the CubeIDE/FreeRTOS integration, check the suitable extensions/expansions of the IDE. Other than that, you have to edit files manually...